# Can't call static method in JavaScript parent class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to access static method `baseArea` from parent class `cars` but it shows following error:

```
test.php:34 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).baseArea is not a function
    at Bike.get bikeArea [as bikeArea] (test.php:34)
    at test.php:42
```

But it works fine when I use `baseArea () {}` instead of `static baseArea() {}`

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Cars {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.height = x;
        this.width = y;
    }

    static baseArea() {
        return 44;
    }
}

class Bike extends Cars {
    constructor(flag) {
        super(flag, flag);
    }

    get bikeArea() {
        return super.baseArea();
    }
}

let bike = new Bike(10);
console.log(bike.bikeArea);
```

Comment: Static functions you usually don't call on the object. you call them on the class.

Comment: `super.baseArea()` should be `Cars.baseArea()`.

Comment: or `Bike.baseArea()`

Comment: Please see the example under **Super class calls with super** here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super They've also called static method using `super` How's that working?

Comment: It may be because the `pingpong` method is also static AND called with `Computer.pingpong()` and not `new Computer().pingpong()` The whole chain is static. Maybe in that circumstances it succeed to resolve the super.

Comment: Also static? That doesn't make difference.

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. It's working now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not work because `super.` is referencing a class instance. And a static method are not attached to instances but to class themselves.

However, the following will work:

```
class Cars {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.height = x;
        this.width = y;
    }

    static baseArea() {
        return 44;
    }
}

class Bike extends Cars {
    constructor(flag) {
        super(flag, flag);
    }

    get bikeArea() {
        return Bike.baseArea();
    }
}
```

Note the `Bike.baseArea()` (which for the sake of readability can be called that way : `Cars.baseArea()`).

In the example that you linked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), it is likely that it works because the pingpong method is also static AND called with Computer.pingpong() and not new Computer().pingpong() The whole chain is static. Maybe in that circumstances it succeed to resolve the super.

Comment: See my comment.

Answer (score 8):

To call parent's *static* method on child's *non-static* method using `super` keyword

```js
class Bike extends Cars {
    get bikeArea() {
        return super.constructor.baseArea();
    }
}
```

However, to call parent's *static* method on child's *static* method using `super` keyword

```js
class Bike extends Cars {
    static bikeArea() {
        return super.baseArea();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this type of comments usually, but this is definitely the most accurate answer and should be the approved answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `Bike.baseArea()` instead of `bike.bikeArea()` as it has been extended to include `Cars`.

### or

You could change,

```
get bikeArea() {
    return super.baseArea();
}
```

to,

```
static bikeArea() {
    return super.baseArea();
}
```

Thereby allowing you to call it as `Bike.bikeArea()`.

Comment: See my comment under question.

Answer (score 3):

You can chnage your

```
get bikeArea(){
   return super.baseArea();
}
```

to

```
get bikeArea(){
   return Cars.baseArea();
}
```

Or you can simply use that:

```
class Cars {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.height = x;
        this.width = y;
    }

    baseArea() {
        return 44;
    }
}

class Bike extends Cars {
    constructor(flag) {
        super(flag, flag);
    }

    bikeArea() {
        return super.baseArea();
    }
}

let bike = new Bike(10);
console.log(bike.bikeArea());
```